# Handling Enums Across System

Tags: c#, angular, rest, enums, mapping

When passing an enum from the backend I've always been skeptical of adding another mapping class on the UI to get the string value of an emum. I'd have to change the code in 2 places if the enum ever changed. But what is the alternative?

I don't want to use constants because in this case the data is in a set so it is much more natural to use an enum. Here is an example of the data:

```
public enum Category
{
    PropertyTaxes,
    PropertyInsurance,
    Utilities,
    Trash,
    PropertyManagement,
    Maintenance,
    Landscaping,
    Pool,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I make a common library project for these types of items, then I just reference the common library inside of my other projects.

This allows you to share the enum, but also keep it controlled.

Comment: Is that still an option in a non-node project, can tyepscript reference a .dll?

Comment: No, you cannot share enums between c# and Typescript.